# How to store full dates & year-only dates in the same field in Microsoft Access?

Tags: database-design

In my database I have a field that for some records has a full date but for others has only a year. Right now I've defined it as a number so I can at least store the year-is there a way I can store full dates in the field too?

Comment: This questions belongs in either SO or SuperUser.

Comment: Trying to overload the purpose of a single field in a database is typically a bad idea.

Comment: @user61852 or DBA.SE.  Though do note that it should only be posted on *one* site at a time.  Furthermore, I believe this question is underspecified to be a good question on any of the sites as it is written.  It should have the information about what problem is trying to be solved (storing dates and year only in the same field is a "how do I implement this solution" which has the danger of being a poorly specified XY problem).

Comment: I agree about posting a question on only one site-and since it's here & I don't know how to move it it'll stay here unless one of you can move it for me. I appreciate that overloading a field is typically a bad idea-do you have a suggestion? The field in question is a copyright date. Some have complete dates & I want to retain that-but many have only a year. How would you handle this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A few options, all with pros and cons:

1. Split the date into it's components, and store them separately (Month, Day, Year).  A bit of over-normalization, but will give you the ability to compare years easily.
2. Store a dummy date (as a date) for the missing value (e.g, 1/1/2015 for dates with years only in 2015).  You lose the visibility of knowing when dates are missing the year, but it gives you one column of the correct type.  You may want to add an additional column  (invisible to the data entry person) that flags year only dates.
3. Store your dates as an integer - 2015 for year, 20150101 for year/month/day.  Will cause some awkwardness when querying because you'll need to validate full dates versus years only, but it's the easiest to implement storage for a single column.